# Как уйти от запятых (авторских), не используя скобок?

Tags: авторская-пунктуация

> Театр – изнутри! А в качестве рассказа об **этом самом общем, и каждый
>   раз особенном,** создании – о спектакле – мы должны собирать красивые
>   видеоклипы, под музыку...

Всем ли понятно, что при рассказе о театре изнутри спектакль - это самое общее?

Может, я неверно понимаю?

Пожалуйста, предлагайте знаки, а то чехарда какая-то.

А если так:

*... в качестве рассказа об этом самом общем – и каждый раз особенном – создании, о спектакле, мы должны...*

Comment: По поводу "самого общего". По замыслу автора, я думаю, слово "общее" противопоставляется слову "особенное". Но я на этом противопоставлении спотыкаюсь. Вряд ли этот ребус можно разгадать с первого прочтения. Но когда ребус разгадан, структура предложения становится простой и понятной.

Comment: Так что, Гризлик, к автору за смыслом?

Comment: Не вижу другого выхода. Но если даже я угадал, всё равно не вижу хорошего решения.